# Is there a libpng12 library for 18.04 LTS arm64?

Tags: 18.04, arm64, libpng

I am trying to make an nVidia Jetson Nano developer board work with a USB camera that seems to operate over a proprietary protocol, since OpenCV 4 can't interact with it like it can with a simple USB webcam. The docs to the camera I'm working with link to an SDK that is used to set up the camera, and comes with code examples of use of the camera. I installed this SDK, but it won't run due to lack of the `libpng12.so.0` shared library file that, I believe, comes with the libpng12 package.
I did a lot of web searching, but failed to find libpng12 specifically for my setup: the board uses Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on an arm64 processor, but I could only find libpng12 for amd64 or and arm64 libpng12 library for 16.04. Does libpng12 for arm64-based Ubuntu 18.04 LTS exist, and if yes, how do I install it?

Comment: You can try simply install library manually by downloading [related deb-packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=arm64&searchon=names&keywords=libpng12).

Comment: Thanks, but I stated in the question that my developer board runs 18.04 arm64 aka Bionic Beaver. The packages you linked to are for Xenial Xerus aka 16.04. @N0rbert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Ubuntu package logs for `libpng` and `libpng12` packages [publishing history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpng/+publishinghistory):

> Removed from disk on 2016-07-08.
> Removal requested on 2016-07-08.
> Deleted on 2016-07-08 by [redacted] RoQA; superseded by libpng1.6;
> [Debian bug #822318](http://bugs.debian.org/822318); [LP: #1595485](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libpng/+bug/1595485)
>
> Published on 2016-04-26

This is superseded by `libpng1.6` packages - however I don't believe that they provide `libpng12.so.0`.

If this is needed by a program you use, whatever SDK you're using needs to be updated to use a newer `libpng` library, namely `libpng1.6` and its packages.

`libpng12` does not exist in Bionic, and was last made available in Xenial Xerus 16.04 (as it was removed in Yakkety 16.10).

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble getting libpng12 for ubuntu 22.04.
I needed it for fltk / fluid.
I tried sim-linking the libpng16 to libpng12, getting deb packages,
trying the ppa: (which gave no installation candidate
messages).

I finally found an answer, download the source code, compile and link it) that worked here: [Install libpng12 on ubuntu 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404213/install-libpng12-on-ubuntu)

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev
cd
mkdir src
cd src
wget https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/libpng12/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng_1.2.54.orig.tar.xz
tar Jxfv libpng_1.2.54.orig.tar.xz
cd libpng-1.2.54
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpng12.so.0.54.0 /usr/lib/libpng12.so
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpng12.so.0.54.0 /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0
```