# Install libpng12 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, libpng

I need to install lipng12-0 on ubuntu 22.04 to make an old Canon printer work.

On 20.04, I followed the instructions given here : [How to correctly install libpng12-0 on the Ubuntu 19.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194386/how-to-correctly-install-libpng12-0-on-the-ubuntu-19-10)

But it seems to no longer work for ubuntu 22.04.

Any ideas to make it work on ubuntu 22.04 ?

Comment: Does `libpng-dev` not work for you? Why do you specifically need `libpng12-dev`?

Comment: In fact I am trying to install a driver for an old ip2600 canon printer. The driver provided by Canon depends on libpng12.
The generic driver (gutenprint) installed automatically does'nt work.

Comment: Can you share the driver? Maybe it would work with libpng, and we can engineer its dependencies. (libpng12 was a very old package and Canon may not have updated the driver).

Comment: Sure, here is the driver https://app.box.com/s/1qky5ib0mlyhyn7760fu1fo9kuxyiyj1
It was packaged for 32-bit but it worked on 64-bit with multiarch support.
There was allready a dependancy issue wit libcupsys2 which was solved by the script provided here : https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1427098&page=2

Comment: Hey, check if this answer works. https://askubuntu.com/a/1240162/124466

Comment: I also tried to change the dependency in the .deb file, but could not repackage it once again because the libraries are in i386, whereas my Ubuntu is amd64.

Comment: I just tried the answer askubuntu.com/a/1240162/124466 you proposed. The packet is installing fine and there are more printers available in the driver database after the installation is completed, but still not my ip2600 printer. I have tried selecting a driver for ip200 or ip 2700 but printing doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

I am in the same boat as you. I recommend compiling from scratch given the source code in the PPA. Basically, this *should* do what you want it to do. It installs essential packages to build, makes a source folder, gets the source, extracts the source, configures the build environment, builds the library, installs the library and set up the necessary symlinks in /usr/lib.

```
sudo apt install build-essential zlib1g-dev
cd
mkdir src
wget https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/linuxuprising/libpng12/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng_1.2.54.orig.tar.xz
tar Jxfv libpng_1.2.54.orig.tar.xz
cd libpng-1.2.54
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpng12.so.0.54.0 /usr/lib/libpng12.so
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/libpng12.so.0.54.0 /usr/lib/libpng12.so.0
```

Hopefully this helps you get that legacy app running. Good luck!

Comment: This is the one got my app running

Comment: I tried this but now it gives `quartus: error while loading shared libraries: libpng12.so.0: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64`

Comment: Seems like you have an old 32-bit version of quartus running on a 64 bit host, try upgrading that quartus binary to 64 bit. 32 bit compilation support is horribly broken on Ubuntu unfortunately. :(

Answer (score 2):

I use a Canon Pixma 8250/8200 Series with Ubuntu 22.04.

Like [Archisman Panigrahi](https://askubuntu.com/users/124466/archisman-panigrahi) mentioned [in a comment above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404213/install-libpng12-on-ubuntu-22-04/1421149#comment2438871_1404213), [the solution from user1083006](https://askubuntu.com/a/1240162/621804) works for me and is very easy:

> For Canon Pixma MG4250 and other "old" Canon printers, the package
> `cups-backend-bjnp` is needed. First install it:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install cups-backend-bjnp
> ```
>
> Then your printer will be avaliable in Ubuntu's list of printers. And you may change the color model to KCMY.

Answer (score 1):

Since the PPA does not yet have packages for Jammy, you can manually install the version for Impish.

Open a terminal and enter the following commands one by one. These commands will download the [.deb packages](https://launchpad.net/%7Elinuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/libpng12/+packages) from Launchpad, and install them manually.

```
mkdir libpng
cd libpng
wget https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/libpng12/+files/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1~ppa0~impish0_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/libpng12/+files/libpng12-dev_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1~ppa0~impish0_amd64.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/libpng12/+files/libpng3_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1+1~ppa0~impish0_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems to fail in my case :  libpng12-dev conflicts with libpng-dev
  libpng-dev:amd64 (version 1.6.37-3build5) is present and installed.
  libpng-dev:i386 (version 1.6.37-3build5) is present and installed.